# Define method's return type when using keyof

Tags: typescript, option-type

Want to create Maybe< T >  class that will contain some object and perform null/undefined checking, before access to object's properties. 
And of course, the resuls ( Maybe< null > or Maybe< TRes> )  should be typed.

Here is an example:

```
class Maybe < T > {
  constructor(public value: T) {}
  static of < P > (obj: P): Maybe < P > {
    return new Maybe(obj);
  }

  map < TResult > (fn: (arg: T) => TResult): Maybe < TResult > {
    return this.isNothing ? nothing : new Maybe(fn(this.value));
  }

  public get < P extends keyof T > (name: P): Maybe < T[P] > {
    return this.isNothing ? nothing : Maybe.of(this.value[name]);
  }
  get isNothing(): boolean {
    return this.value == null;
  }
}
let nothing = new Maybe(null);
```

Everethisng works fine here and typed. For exaple:

```
class Test {
  a = {
    id: 1,
    name: "test1"
  };
  f = (foo: string) => {
    return new Test();
  };
};

let t = new Test();

console.log(Maybe.of(t).get('a').get('name').value); // ok
```

But have a problem with defining "apply" function, that will accept name of object's property, that is actually a function, execute that function and return Maybe< TResult >.

```
  // T[fName]: (...args)=> TResult
  public apply < P extends keyof T > (fnName: P, ...args: any[]) /*: Maybe<Tresult> */ {
    if (!this.isNothing) {
      let res = null;
      let fn = this.value[fnName];

      if (isF(fn)) {
        return Maybe.of(fn(...args));
      }

    }
    return nothing;
  }
```

Can't find a solution to define result of  "apply" call.

```
let fResult = Maybe.of(t).apply('f', 'foo');
// fResult is Maybe<any> ,  expected to be Maybe<Test>
```

Is anybody knows how to define type for "apply" result?  Or even this possible in TS 2.3?

Here the link on playground with same code:
[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=%20%20function%20isF(fn)%3A%20fn%20is%20Function%20%7B%20%20%2F%2Ftypeguard%20stub%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20class%20Maybe%20%3C%20T%20%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20value%3A%20T)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20static%20of%20%3C%20P%20%3E%20(obj%3A%20P)%3A%20Maybe%20%3C%20P%20%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Maybe(obj)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20map%20%3C%20TResult%20%3E%20(fn%3A%20(arg%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20TResult)%3A%20Maybe%20%3C%20TResult%20%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.isNothing%20%3F%20nothing%20%3A%20new%20Maybe(fn(this.value))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20get%20%3C%20P%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3E%20(name%3A%20P)%3A%20Maybe%20%3C%20T%5BP%5D%20%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.isNothing%20%3F%20nothing%20%3A%20Maybe.of(this.value%5Bname%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20T%5BfName%5D%3A%20(...args)%3D%3E%20TResult%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20apply%20%3C%20P%20extends%20keyof%20T%20%3E%20(fnName%3A%20P%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%2F*%3A%20Maybe%3CTresult%3E%20*%2F%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(!this.isNothing)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20res%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20fn%20%3D%20this.value%5BfnName%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(isF(fn))%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Maybe.of(fn(...args))%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20nothing%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20isNothing()%3A%20boolean%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.value%20%3D%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20let%20nothing%20%3D%20new%20Maybe(null)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20class%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22test1%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20f%20%3D%20(foo%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20let%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20console.log(Maybe.of(t).get('a').get('name').value)%3B%20%2F%2F%20ok%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20let%20fResult%20%3D%20Maybe.of(t).apply('f'%2C%20'foo')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20fResult%20is%20Maybe%3Cany%3E%20%2C%20%20expected%20to%20be%20Maybe%3CTest%3E)

Thanks

Comment: I'm not clear on what your question is. In your playground code, you have simply forgot to declare the type argument `Tresult`. Nevermind, I misread, I see the issue.

Comment: I think this question can be condensed a bit, it's not immediately clear what you want. It seems you're simply asking how to get a method's return type when using `keyof`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible without a way of detecting and ensuring that 'f' is indeed the name of a function (somehow expressing `P extends keyof T, TR, T[P] extends (...args: any[]) => TR`).

Answer (score 1):

First, let me put aside `Maybe<T>` class and introduce some basic operations, one step at a time.

You can have generic function that will check if the object is not null, and then return some property of that object. Return type of the function can be inferred from the type of the property:

```
function maybeGet<T, N extends keyof T>(t: T | undefined, n: N) {
  return t ? t[n] : undefined;
}
```

with your `Test` class

```
class Test {
  a = {
    id: 1,
    name: "test1"
  };
  f = (foo: string) => {
    return new Test();
  };
};

let t = new Test();
```

you can use it like this

```
const a = maybeGet(t, 'a');
```

and indeed the type of `a` is inferred as  `{ id: number; name: string; }`

Then you can define generic type alias describing some function with return type `R`:

```
type FR<R> = (...args: any[]) => R;
```

and then define generic function that will take another function, and call it if it's not null. Return type of the function is inferred from the return type of its argument:

```
function maybeApplyFunction<R>(f: FR<R> | undefined, ...args: any[]) {
  return f ? f(...args) : undefined; 
}

const r = maybeApplyFunction(t.f, 'foo'); // r has type 'Test'
```

You can combine the two together explicitly, without a problem

```
const tf = maybeApplyFunction(maybeGet(t, 'f'), 'foo'); 
// tf has type `Test`
```

The problem is to combine the two in one generic operation.

Using mapped type, you can try to define type alias for an object which has a function returning `R` as a property

```
type FM<N extends string, R> = {[n in N]: FR<R>};
```

and write generic function using that

```
function maybeApplyMemberFunction<N extends string, R>(o: FM<N, R>, n: N, ...args: any[]) {
  return o ? o[n](...args) : undefined;
}
```

and it will even work for some cases

```
class T1 { f() { return new T1() } };

const b = maybeApplyMemberFunction(new T1(), 'f');
// b has type T1
```

however, it will not work for your test because TypeScript for some reason will use `keyof T` as `N` and insist that all properties in `Test` must be callable:

```
const tm = maybeApplyMemberFunction(t, 'f');

// Argument of type 'Test' is not assignable to parameter of type 
// 'FM<"a" | "f", Test>'.
  // Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
    // Type '{ id: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FR<Test>'.
      //  Type '{ id: number; name: string; }' provides no match for the signature
      // '(...args: any[]): Test'.
```

[code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20maybeGet%3CT%2C%20N%20extends%20keyof%20T%3E(t%3A%20T%20%7C%20undefined%2C%20n%3A%20N)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20t%20%3F%20t%5Bn%5D%20%3A%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22test1%22%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20f%20%3D%20(foo%3A%20string)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20a%20%3D%20maybeGet(t%2C%20'a')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FR%3CR%3E%20%3D%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20R%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20maybeApplyFunction%3CR%3E(f%3A%20FR%3CR%3E%20%7C%20undefined%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20f%20%3F%20f(...args)%20%3A%20undefined%3B%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20r%20%3D%20maybeApplyFunction(t.f%2C%20'foo')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20tf%20%3D%20maybeApplyFunction(maybeGet(t%2C%20'f')%2C%20'foo')%3B%20%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FM%3CN%20extends%20string%2C%20R%3E%20%3D%20%7B%5Bn%20in%20N%5D%3A%20FR%3CR%3E%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20maybeApplyMemberFunction%3CN%20extends%20string%2C%20R%3E(o%3A%20FM%3CN%2C%20R%3E%2C%20n%3A%20N%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20o%20%3F%20o%5Bn%5D(...args)%20%3A%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20T1%20%7B%20f()%20%7B%20return%20new%20T1()%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20b%20%3D%20maybeApplyMemberFunction(new%20T1()%2C%20'f')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20tm%20%3D%20maybeApplyMemberFunction(t%2C%20'f')%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20maybeApplyMemberFunctionF%3CN%20extends%20'f'%2C%20R%3E(o%3A%20FM%3CN%2C%20R%3E%2C%20n%3A%20N%2C%20...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20o%20%3F%20o%5Bn%5D(...args)%20%3A%20undefined%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aconst%20t1%20%3D%20maybeApplyMemberFunctionF(t%2C%20'f')%3B%0D%0A)

If you limit `N` to exact literal type it works:

```
function maybeApplyMemberFunctionF<N extends 'f', R>(o: FM<N, R>, n: N, ...args: any[]) {
  return o ? o[n](args) : undefined;
}
const t1 = maybeApplyMemberFunctionF(t, 'f');
```

Unfortunately typescript does not have a way to specify that `N` should be the exact literal type of the `n` argument.